# How to fix "IntegrityError Foreign Key constraint failed" error in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have Client (AbstractUser) and Team models in my django app

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Client(AbstractUser):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True, related_name='client', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    pass
```

So, when I logged in using Client (not superuser, with permission to add-change Client) I can't change Client. I want to be one administrator for each team to manage own team, can add or change Client. So Client with permission is_staff  can manage own team. But it gives an error IntegrityError. Django admin.py